# Dynamically named SQL fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query that, given a starting date, gives that week and the next 11 weeks' summarized data. Currently the field names for the weeks are week1, week2... Is there a way to name the fields with the dates they represent? (using only SQL)

If the given input is #11/9/13# then I'm looking for something like this.

```
SELECT
    [Qry Week Totals By Billto and CC].CC,
    Sum([Qry Week Totals By Billto and CC].[Week 1]) AS [inputdate],
    Sum([Qry Week Totals By Billto and CC].[Week 2]) AS [inputdate] +7 ...
FROM
    ...
```

Of course this doesn't work for me. But I hope it communicates what I'm looking for.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Although this may be possible (I'm not sure), it would probably be bad practice as it complicated reading the returned results for any other scripts. It would be better to add the date in as a column and de-pivot the output.

Comment: you could use VBA in access to do this in Visual Basic, but I already gave the answer for SQL server and deleted it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Some day I'll be able to use cool SQL like you suggested. For now I'm stuck. AeroX, I agree that this is a bad idea, However this is the final output of the database and no other queries use this one.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to work something out with partition before you crosstab:

```
SELECT Partition([adate], #3/1/2013#, #4/1/2013#, 7) AS Part1,
       table1.adate,
       Mid([part1], 1, Instr([part1], ":") - 1) AS Mid1,
       Mid([part1], Instr([part1], ":") + 1) AS Mid2,
       Format([mid1], "yyyy/mm/dd") & " - " & Format([mid2], "yyyy/mm/dd") AS
       TheDateRange
FROM   table1
WHERE  table1.adate>#3/6/2013#
```

Otherwise, you might consider a bucket table.